# Maven: How to read system properties from a file and pass those properties into a Cargo container?

Tags: maven

I would like a robust way of reading all system properties from an env.properties file and pass those properties' names and values into the Cargo container instead of hard coding the values as in the followings.

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <container>
                <containerId>${cargo.container}</containerId>
                <type>installed</type>
                <home>${cargo.container.home}</home>
                <systemProperties>
                    <somedb.name>sdm-db</somedb.name>
                    <somedb.user>Administrator</somedb.user>
                    <somedb.password>password</somedb.password>
                </systemProperties>
            </container>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>read-env.properties</id>
    <phase>initialize</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <files>
        <file>env.properties</file>
        </files>
    </configuration>
    </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I wonder if properties-maven-plugin is a way to go? After reading properties from a file, how do I pass them into Cargo container?

I got an error saying: Could not load properties from URL [file://${env.properties}]: ${env.properties}

Any advice is greatly appreciated.